# SimeReplacing WeekOfYear Dynamically

Tags: mdx, azure-data-factory, mdx-query

I am using copy activity in ADF in which i have following pseudo query:

```
SELECT
    {
        [Measures].[**************],
        [Measures].[**************],
        [Measures].[**************]
    } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
    { 
        [0CALWEEK].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS 
    } 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES  MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM cubeName/ReportName
SAP VARIABLES [SAP_VARIABLE_NAME] 
INCLUDING [0CALWEEK].[201905]
```

In the above i want to replace '201905' dynamically,there is no current function availabe to get WeekOfYear in ADF Expressions and functions OR can i use MDX Query to generate WeekOfYear

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example how it changes value for a member value. Please note I have answerd if from phone so some syntax issue might exist.

With member measures.t
As
Case when

[0CALWEEK].[LEVEL01]. currentmember.name="'201905"
Then 1
Else
0
End

SELECT
    {
        [Measures].[t]
    } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
    { 
        [0CALWEEK].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS 
    }  ON ROWS 
FROM cubeName/ReportName

Comment: @user2459702 did it help?